# Simple Syntax-Highlighter to use in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editor, syntax-highlighting

There are a lot of Syntax-Highlighter on web, But there are not simple. Is there any simple syntax highlighter with file upload and codemirror like stackoverflow's.

Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing simple about automated syntax highlighting. Not sure what you are looking for. [Here's the one I wrote](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/colorizing-source-code).

Comment: may be a javascript library or a tool like ckeditor. but ck editor is not good for code editing/highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://oneqonea.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-do-i-add-syntax-highlighting-to-my.html

You may be able to glean the information you need to suit your ASP.NET MVC implementation. The tutorial basically illustrates what http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ has to offer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Note that this is a client-side solution that runs JavaScript in the visitor's browser.